# Changing the Date Format in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript, I'm getting the Date & Time as `1/05/2013 20:00` (d/mm/yyyy HH:MM)

But I want the date & time in this format `01/05/2013 20:00` (dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM)

Comment: Use this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: have a look at date.js.. easy to use and come in handy for all date related issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't offer any help with date/time formatting.

If you want something sophisticated without much hazzle, take [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

However, if adding a "0" to the beginning of the date is everything you ever want, this will be enough:

```
var date = "1/05/2013 20:00";

function modifyDateAccordingToYourNeeds(date_in)
{
    var day_part = date_in.split("/")[0];
    if (day_part.length == 1)
        date_in = "0" + date_in;

    return date_in;
}

alert(modifyDateAccordingToYourNeeds(date));
```

However, be careful as this approach is very limited.

Comment: What do you mean by limited?

Comment: @User Limited in the sense of "can only handle your requirement of adding a 0 to the beginning of the string, if not already present". If you should later decide to use a different format like YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, you better directly stick to solutions like date.js.

Answer (score 2):

maybe use this

```
var curr_date = date.getDate();
var curr_month = date.getMonth();
var curr_year = date.getFullYear();

date= curr_date + '/'+ curr_month + '/'+ curr_year;
```

Answer (score 2):

More possibilities

Javascript

```
var d = "1/05/2013 20:00";

function padDay(date) {
    if (date.charAt(1) === "/") {
        date = "0" + date;
    }

    return date;
}

console.log(padDay(d));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/V44Wf/)

or with [moments](http://momentjs.com/)

Javascript

```
var d = "1/05/2013 20:00";

function padDay(date) {
    return moment(d, "D/M/YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
}

console.log(padDay(d));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/BJdcr/)

Answer (score 2):

The [Globalize library](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) allows you to do both globalization and customization of dates easily. The following example is taken from the [documentation page](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#format):

```
Globalize.format( new Date(1955,10,5), "dddd MMMM d, yyyy" ); // "Saturday November 5, 1955"
```

The globalize library also allows you to output dates in a format appropriate for the culture specified. It supports virtually all available cultures. Another example:

```
// assuming a culture with "/" as the date separator symbol 
Globalize.format( new Date(1955,10,5), "yyyy/MM/dd" ); // "1955/11/05"
```

If you want to do any more globalization, the Globalize library also allows for number and currency globalization. I have created a small sample project that shows how to use this library for client-side globalization: https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/clientsideglobalization

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function changeFormat(string) {
    var p = string; //"1/05/2013 20:00"
    var n = /^[0-9]*/.exec(p)[0];
    p = p.replace(n, "");
    if (n.length == 1) {
        n = "0" + n;
    }
    return n + p;
}
```

---

```
alert(changeFormat("1/05/2013 20:00"));
```